# Passing Data between state Providers in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, router

Im looking to pass data between 2 controllers in Angular, Below is code i started

There are 2 views  one with input field and other with a link.
when i click on link in the second view i should be able to set a state and state data should be populated in input field in first field.

I tried several approaches but im missing something.
Can someone help me here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.10" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>        
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider','$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {   
        var addBook = {
                name: 'addBook',
                url: '/addBook',
                template: '<h2>Add A book</h2> Data from View  <input type="text" ng-model={{input-text}}>'  ,
                data:""
            },
            viewBookv = {
                name: 'viewBookv',
                url: '/viewBook',                  
                   template: '<h2>View A book</h2><a href="#" ng-click="edit()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">Edit</span></a> ' ,
            };
            $stateProvider.state(addBook, "controller: editUserCtrl");
        $stateProvider.state(viewBookv, "controller: editUserCtrl");   

    }])

myApp.controller('editUserCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.paramOne = $stateParams.data;
         $scope.edit = function () {
         event.preventDefault();                 

            $state.go("addBook");

    }

})


myApp.controller('mainController',function($scope, $rootScope, $state,$window){   

  $scope.addBook=function(){

    $state.go("addBook");

    };
   $scope.viewbookls= function(){


    $state.go("viewBookv");

    };

})
</script>

 </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="mainController">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#"     ng-click="viewbookls()"> View Book </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"     ng-click="addBook()"> Add Book </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
             <div ui-view></div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>       

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your end goal to just share state between two controllers?

Comment: yes, Im trying to access using the pattern state.current.data, but couldnt access it at the end

Answer (score 4):

Typically in angular the way to share state between controllers is using a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). So the way it's usually set up is to setup a service then import that service into the relevant controllers, and that data gets shared between them. I've modified your example above to follow this pattern(I'm not quite sure what you were trying to do)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.10" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>        
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {   
        var addBook = {
                name: 'addBook',
                url: '/addBook',
                template: '<h2>Add A book</h2> Data from View <button ng-click="updateBook()">Update</button>  <input type="text" ng-model="inputText">'  ,
                controller: "addBookCtrl",
                data:""
            },
            viewBookv = {
                name: 'viewBooks',
                url: '/viewBook',                  
                template: '<h2>View A book</h2><div ng-repeat="book in bookList">{{book}}</div>',
                controller: "viewBookCtrl",
            };
            $stateProvider.state('addBook', addBook);
        $stateProvider.state('viewBooks', viewBookv);   

    }])

myApp.controller('addBookCtrl', function($scope, bookService) { 
  $scope.updateBook = function(){
    console.log( $scope.inputText)
    bookService.books.push($scope.inputText);
  }
})

myApp.controller('viewBookCtrl', function($scope, bookService) { 
  $scope.bookList = bookService.books
})

myApp.factory('bookService', function() {
  var bookService = {};
  bookService.books = [];
  return bookService;
});


myApp.controller('mainController',function($scope, $rootScope, $state,$window){   

  $scope.addBook=function(){

    $state.go("addBook");

    };
   $scope.viewbookls= function(){


    $state.go("viewBooks");

    };

})
</script>

 </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="mainController">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#"     ng-click="viewbookls()"> View Book </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"     ng-click="addBook()"> Add Book </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
             <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>       

</body>
</html>
```

What this example does, is in the text box for add book, you type in the name (then click update), this appends it to an array so every time you do it you'll get a new element on that array. From there head over to the view books page, and you'll see all the different things you typed in.